# “apt-get purge” fails due to "unmet dependencies" error despite the dependencies already being installed

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I am on Debian Stretch. When I try to run apt-get purge, it fails with an unmet dependencies error:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge -f openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim-gtk : Depends: libruby2.3 (>= 2.3.0~preview2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

The last line seems to indicate that libruby2.3 cannot be installed, but both it and vim-gtk are already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy vim-gtk
vim-gtk:
  Installed: 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3
  Candidate: 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 500
        500 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ sudo apt-cache policy libruby2.3
libruby2.3:
  Installed: 2.3.3-1+deb9u9
  Candidate: 2.3.3-1+deb9u9
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.3-1+deb9u9 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.3-1+deb9u8 500
        500 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable/main amd64 Packages
```

I've tried purging and reinstalling vim-gtk and libruby2.3, and this seems to work:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge vim-gtk libruby2.3
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk libruby2.3
```

However, after this, I still get the same error when running `sudo apt-get purge -f openssl`. What is causing this error? Why is apt telling me it is not going to be installed when it is already installed?

I've tried some of the suggestions from other similar questions (`sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo apt-get update/clean/autoremove`, but the error persists)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge -m -s openssl` ? What happens?

Comment: I got the same error as without the -m -s flags

Answer (score 0):

*this is the beginning of what **might** end up as an answer:*

I can't tell whether removing openssl is a WISE thing to do; I'm leaning towards "Not wise".

This is what is present in my current Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
$ dpkg --list | head -n 4 && dpkg --list |  grep openssl
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                               Architecture Description
ii  libevent-openssl-2.1-7:amd64                  2.1.11-stable-1                       amd64        Asynchronous event notification library (openssl)
ii  openssl                                       1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1                     amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  perl-openssl-defaults:amd64                   4                                     amd64        version compatibility baseline for Perl OpenSSL packages
```

Comment: Perhaps it is unwise. I didn't realize that there were so many other packages in the system which depend on openssl. If I understand correctly, the error "vim-gtk : Depends: libruby2.3 (>= 2.3.0~preview2) but it is not going to be installed" is happening because libruby2.3 depends on openssl, is that correct? If this is the case, why doesn't apt offer to remove libruby2.3 and vim-gtk along with openssl?

Comment: Hmm... forgotten thing here. Not really knowing the exact details here, but I have gotten the impression that package inter-dependencies can be a horrific thing at times. Not always possible to solve in a sane manner, especially by automated and general scripting. One such headache package appears to be Python updates in Ubuntus, due to the heavy dependency from apt / apt-get . A similar situation may be present with openssl - outside of my knowledge.